# Update websocket server asynchronously inside a loop with Python

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I'm reading data from the PLC of a machine using a Python script. The core of the script is a while loop that runs every second and reads whatever data the machine sends. What I want to do is saving the data in a database and, at the same time, "publishing" some of the data using websockets so that I can show it in realtime on a web application. The db part is working.

For my other goal, I've been reading [websockets documentation](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html) and I've started a very simple websocket server like this

```
import asyncio
import websockets


async def create_socket(data):
    async def hello(websocket, path):
        await websocket.send(data)

    start_server = websockets.serve(hello, "localhost", 5678)

    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

The "data" input is a json and I can read it without any problems from my JS script but this, of course, blocks the main queue and, since I'm calling the above code from the mentioned while loop, I can't get pass the first iteration. What I would like to do is continuing to go through my while loop and asynchronously update the websocket with the data I read from the plc at every iteration.

Do you have any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you make your PLC code async and put it in the same event loop? That is how asyncio was designed to be used.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Should I get rid of the while loop and do that with asyncio?

Comment: If you can, sure. But be aware that in asyncio any _blocking_ call must be async. So if the call you use to read the data can block, you need to find an async library to do it with.